# Hibernate 3.6.10 Dependency resolution

Tags: hibernate, ivy, slf4j

I recently upgraded a project to use hibernate 3.6.10.Final. The project uses ivy to retrieve and the dependencies. Now I'm getting an error that a method in slf4j cannot be found. I believe that this is due to conflicting slf4j dependencies between hibernate-core (requires 1.6.1) and hibernate-commons-annotations (requires 1.5.8). According to the hibernate-core ivy.xml hibernate-core is dependent on hibernate-commons-annotations.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
 Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.info(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:303)
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit>(JavaReflectionManager.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.createReflectionManager(Configuration.java:2988)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.createReflectionManager(Configuration.java:2984)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:307)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:302)
        at mb.common.hibernate.cfg.DefaultEnhancedConfiguration.<init>(DefaultEnhancedConfiguration.java:10)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
```

I checked the old slf4j javadoc and sure enough it looks like slf4j-1.6.1 has a format method that returns a FomattingTuple as opposed to a String.

Here's the **hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final ivy.xml** file that was retrieved from the maven2 repository:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="org.hibernate"
        module="hibernate-core"
        revision="3.6.10.Final"
        status="release"
        publication="20120208201903"
    >
        <description homepage="">
        The core functionality of Hibernate
        </description>
        <m:dependency.management__javassist__javassist__version>3.12.0.GA</m:dependency.management__javassist__javassist__version>
        <m:properties__bytemanVersion>1.5.1</m:properties__bytemanVersion>
        <m:dependency.management__commons-collections__commons-collections__version>3.1</m:dependency.management__commons-collections__commons-collections__version>
        <m:dependency.management__javax.validation__validation-api__version>1.0.0.GA</m:dependency.management__javax.validation__validation-api__version>
        <m:dependency.management__dom4j__dom4j__version>1.6.1</m:dependency.management__dom4j__dom4j__version>
        <m:dependency.management__org.hibernate__hibernate-validator__version>4.1.0.Final</m:dependency.management__org.hibernate__hibernate-validator__version>
        <m:dependency.management__cglib__cglib__version>2.2</m:dependency.management__cglib__cglib__version>
        <m:dependency.management__org.hibernate.javax.persistence__hibernate-jpa-2.0-api__version>1.0.1.Final</m:dependency.management__org.hibernate.javax.persistence__hibernate-jpa-2.0-api__version>
        <m:dependency.management__com.h2database__h2__version>1.2.145</m:dependency.management__com.h2database__h2__version>
        <m:properties__project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</m:properties__project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <m:properties__slf4jVersion>1.6.1</m:properties__slf4jVersion>
        <m:dependency.management__org.slf4j__slf4j-api__version>1.6.1</m:dependency.management__org.slf4j__slf4j-api__version>
        <m:dependency.management__antlr__antlr__version>2.7.6</m:dependency.management__antlr__antlr__version>
        <m:dependency.management__org.hibernate__hibernate-commons-annotations__version>3.2.0.Final</m:dependency.management__org.hibernate__hibernate-commons-annotations__version>
        <m:properties__antlrPluginVersion>2.1</m:properties__antlrPluginVersion>
        <m:dependency.management__org.jboss.byteman__byteman__version>1.5.1</m:dependency.management__org.jboss.byteman__byteman__version>
        <m:maven.plugins>org.jboss.maven.plugins__maven-jdocbook-style-plugin__null|org.codehaus.groovy.maven__gmaven-plugin__1.0|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-enforcer-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-compiler-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-jar-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-surefire-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-source-plugin__null|org.jboss.maven.plugins__maven-jdocbook-style-plugin__null|org.codehaus.groovy.maven__gmaven-plugin__1.0|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-enforcer-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-compiler-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-jar-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-surefire-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-source-plugin__null|org.codehaus.mojo__antlr-maven-plugin__2.1|org.jboss.maven.plugins__maven-injection-plugin__null|null__maven-jar-plugin__null</m:maven.plugins>
    </info>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="runtime dependencies and master artifact can be used with this conf" extends="runtime,master"/>
        <conf name="master" visibility="public" description="contains only the artifact published by this module itself, with no transitive dependencies"/>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths."/>
        <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it. It is only available on the compilation classpath, and is not transitive."/>
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath." extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test" visibility="private" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases." extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="system" visibility="public" description="this scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository."/>
        <conf name="sources" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the source artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the javadoc artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="optional" visibility="public" description="contains all optional dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="hibernate-core" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
        <artifact name="hibernate-core" type="source" ext="jar" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources"/>
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="antlr" name="antlr" rev="2.7.6" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="commons-collections" name="commons-collections" rev="3.1" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="dom4j" name="dom4j" rev="1.6.1" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)">
            <exclude org="xml-apis" module="xml-apis" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-commons-annotations" rev="3.2.0.Final" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate.javax.persistence" name="hibernate-jpa-2.0-api" rev="1.0.1.Final" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="javax.validation" name="validation-api" rev="1.0.0.GA" force="true" conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="4.1.0.Final" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="javax.xml.bind" name="jaxb-api" rev="2.2" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)">
            <exclude org="javax.xml.stream" module="stax-api" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
            <exclude org="javax.activation" module="activation" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="com.sun.xml.bind" name="jaxb-impl" rev="2.1.12" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="javassist" name="javassist" rev="3.12.0.GA" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="cglib" name="cglib" rev="2.2" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="javax.transaction" name="jta" rev="1.1" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.jboss.javaee" name="jboss-jacc-api_JDK4" rev="1.1.0" force="true" conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)">
            <exclude org="org.jboss.javaee" module="jboss-servlet-api_3.0" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
            <exclude org="org.jboss.logging" module="jboss-logging-spi" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
            <exclude org="org.jboss" module="jboss-common-core" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="ant" name="ant" rev="1.6.5" force="true" conf="provided->compile(*),provided(*),runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="com.h2database" name="h2" rev="1.2.145" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.1" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="3.8.1" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.6.1" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.6.1" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="99.0-does-not-exist" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging-api" rev="99.0-does-not-exist" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <override org="commons-collections" module="commons-collections" matcher="exact" rev="3.1"/>
        <override org="org.hibernate" module="hibernate-validator" matcher="exact" rev="4.1.0.Final"/>
        <override org="javassist" module="javassist" matcher="exact" rev="3.12.0.GA"/>
        <override org="org.jboss.byteman" module="byteman" matcher="exact" rev="1.5.1"/>
        <override org="cglib" module="cglib" matcher="exact" rev="2.2"/>
        <override org="org.hibernate.javax.persistence" module="hibernate-jpa-2.0-api" matcher="exact" rev="1.0.1.Final"/>
        <override org="com.h2database" module="h2" matcher="exact" rev="1.2.145"/>
        <override org="org.hibernate" module="hibernate-commons-annotations" matcher="exact" rev="3.2.0.Final"/>
        <override org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-api" matcher="exact" rev="1.6.1"/>
        <override org="antlr" module="antlr" matcher="exact" rev="2.7.6"/>
        <override org="javax.validation" module="validation-api" matcher="exact" rev="1.0.0.GA"/>
        <override org="dom4j" module="dom4j" matcher="exact" rev="1.6.1"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Here's the **hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final ivy.xml** file that was retrieved from the maven2 repository:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="org.hibernate"
        module="hibernate-commons-annotations"
        revision="3.2.0.Final"
        status="release"
        publication="20100309114153"
    >
        <license name="GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE" url="http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.txt" />
        <description homepage="http://hibernate.org">
        Common reflection code used in support of annotation processing
        </description>
        <m:dependency.management__org.slf4j__slf4j-api__version>1.5.8</m:dependency.management__org.slf4j__slf4j-api__version>
        <m:properties__slf4jVersion>1.5.8</m:properties__slf4jVersion>
        <m:maven.plugins>org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-compiler-plugin__null</m:maven.plugins>
    </info>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="runtime dependencies and master artifact can be used with this conf" extends="runtime,master"/>
        <conf name="master" visibility="public" description="contains only the artifact published by this module itself, with no transitive dependencies"/>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths."/>
        <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it. It is only available on the compilation classpath, and is not transitive."/>
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath." extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test" visibility="private" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases." extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="system" visibility="public" description="this scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository."/>
        <conf name="sources" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the source artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the javadoc artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="optional" visibility="public" description="contains all optional dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="hibernate-commons-annotations" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
        <artifact name="hibernate-commons-annotations" type="source" ext="jar" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources"/>
        <artifact name="hibernate-commons-annotations" type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="javadoc" m:classifier="javadoc"/>
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.5.8" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="3.8.1" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.5.8" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.5.8" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="99.0-does-not-exist" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging-api" rev="99.0-does-not-exist" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <override org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-api" matcher="exact" rev="1.5.8"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

How am I supposed to resolve this dependency conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that only one copy of the slf4j jar can be used on the classpath, so you need to decide which one to keep. Choosing the older version might fix one compilation error, but cause another :-)

By default, ivy will choose the latest one on the assumption that it would be backwardly compatible. You can override this behaviour by using a [conflict](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/conflict.html) indicator as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="3.6.10.Final" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.5.8" conf="compile->default"/>

    <conflict org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-api" rev="1.5.8"/>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I ended up using an older version of hibernate where I wasn't getting conflicts anymore. The major issue was that there were some API changes between the different versions of slf4j that were breaking my build.