# Ivy resolve with HttpClient 3.1 and 4.x

Tags: selenium, dependencies, httpclient, ivy

I have some legacy project that has transitive dependency on commons-httpclient 3.1. Now I am trying to do Selenium 2 WebDrive test on it. Selenium 2 requires Httpclient 4.+ as I understand. Although both will be resolved and put into classpath, IDE will complain

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setSoReuseaddr(Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;Z)V
```

as HttpConnectionParams in Httpclient 3.1 does not have the method.

I searched Internet and found this http://blog.teamextension.com/migrating-from-httpclient-3-1-to-4-0-34 and many other posts. Mostly people manually replace the jars and modify the import paths in the source code.

Since I am not allowed to edit the existing source code. I wonder if there is anyway to configure the Ivy.xml to force out the old dependency, or make the new added Selenium problem to use the new Httpclient/core/mime etc. I tried to exclude commons-httpclient module-wide, but somehow it is still in the classpath.

Hope I explain the question clearly. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Very similar to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871838/hibernate-3-6-10-dependency-resolution/11892931#11892931