# Apache Ivy dependencies force="true" does not work

Tags: java, ant, ivy

My project has commons-codec as a dependency and uses Ivy.
Some other dependencies need commons-codec-1.6 and 1.2.

Now my problem is that Ivy evicts my version(1.4) and instead uses 1.6.
`<dependency org="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" force="true" rev="1.4" />`

Why doesn't force work? Has anyone encountered this yet?

FYI i have used this before and it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [conflict](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/conflict.html) indicator, to override the default behaviour which will be to choose the latest revision of the same dependency.

For an example see the following answer:

- [Hibernate 3.6.10 Dependency resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871838/hibernate-3-6-10-dependency-resolution/11892931#11892931)